# Mongoose findById() - Not Working, Tried all the functions to get document by ID, None of them works

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native

Mongoose findById not working.
It only works when i call just Course.find();

Here's my code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost/mongo-exercises")
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch((err) => console.error("Could not connect to MongoDB", err));

  const courseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  tags: [String],
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  name: String,
  author: String,
  isPublished: Boolean,
  price: Number,
});

const Course = mongoose.model("Course", courseSchema);

async function updateCourse(id){
    const course = await Course.findById(id);
    if(!course) return ;
    console.log(course);
    course.isPublished = true;
    course.author = "Changed Author";
    
    const result = await course.save();
    
    console.log(result);
}
async function getCourses() {
    const courses = await Course.find();
    console.log(courses);
}
updateCourse('5a68fdd7bee8ea64649c2777');
```

[image: These are all the documents i have none of them can be changed]

My VSCODE terminal shows this response

```
anuragtj@Anurags-MacBook-Pro exercise % node index.js           
Connected to MongoDB
```

It just stops at connected to mongodb shows nothing else.

I tried multiple ways of getting document byiD none of them works , and i think its a problem in my db, because none of the methods are working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database is showing that the `_id` fields are stored as type `String`, but your schema doesn't reflect that (which means that Mongoose will assume that `_id` is of type `ObjectId`, and will convert it to that type before making a query).

If you add `_id` to your schema the queries will start working:

```
const courseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id : String,
  ...
});
```

However, I would suggest fixing the main issue, namely a schema mismatch between the code writing to the database and this code that's querying the database.

Answer (score 0):

just add up all the schema also _id cause it will be updated using the vs code on the database so schema should always present there on the vs code modifier...

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you mean but currently the answer seems to duplicate already existing one but with fewer details. Maybe there is a way you could enrich your answer and provide additional info?

Comment: i just want to say that if you define _id also in your schema then it will be able to update it in database